# rpmbuild does not preserve permissions of directories

Tags: linux, file-permissions, rpmbuild

I have an application in /opt/MyApp that I need to pack into an RPM package using [FPM](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/wiki) as follows:

```
fpm -e -s dir -t rpm --name 'MyApp' --version '1.0' --iteration "12345" --directories /opt/MyApp --epoch 0 /opt/MyApp
```

(other options are not relevant here)

All files and directories in MyApp are owned by root (both user and group). Also there is a directory called "help" with different permissions like

```
drwxrwxrwx.
```

i.e. all users can write into that directory.
When I inspect the spec file generated by FPM, it has

```
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
```

and all directories (%dir) and files are then listed, so I would expect that all original permissions are preserved in this package. However, when I inspect it using

```
rpm -qlvp MyApp.rpm
```

the permission on the "help" directory are reset to:

```
drwxrwxr-x
```

i.e. other users cannot write there anymore.
My first guess was to add the option

```
--rpm-use-file-permissions
```

but it made things even worse, because now all files in RPM are owned by the user that called FPM.

Edited:
I've achieved the result using

```
--rpm-use-file-permissions --rpm-user root --rpm-group root
```

but still it doesn't feel elegant and flexible.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The comment about `%defattr`, and absence of comments about the `BUILDROOT` tree may indicate some confusion.  According to [rpm.org](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/s1-rpm-inside-files-list-directives.html):

> If a particular attribute does not need to be specified (usually because the file is **installed** with that attribute set properly), then that attribute may be replaced with a dash

That is, if no explicit permission is given in `%defattr`, then the permissions from build-time **`%install`** when constructing the rpm are satisfactory.  There is no guarantee that those match (or are even compatible with) the actual system on which the rpm is later installed.